# AWS: AccessDeniedException: User: {user} is not authorized to perform: quicksight:ListDashboards on resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-quicksight

I'm getting
`AccessDeniedException: User: {user{ is not authorized to perform: quicksight:ListDashboards on resource` but I cannot find where I can give access to the user to do this operation. Where/how can I give this permission? I've searched for the action on IAM policies but can't find it.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/APIReference/API_ListDashboards.html

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and there's truly a dearth of QuickSight help available online.  Here's the policy you need to attach to your user's IAM role, assuming you want the user to have access to list all dashboards in your account:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "quicksight:ListDashboards"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:quicksight:*:<your-AWS-acct-id>:dashboard/*"
        }
    ]
}
```